# How do I produce a count down using a nested for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, nested, countdown

I want the user to input an integer, and then I want my program to be able to count down to zero starting from that number using a nested `For` loop statement. For example:
*user enters 20*
20
19 18 
17 16 15 
14 13 12 11 
10 9 8 7 6 
5  4  3 2 1 0 
I also want the numbers to be printed out in a half pyramid structure, similar to the example shown above. Here is my attempt to solve this problem. Note that I've used a variable and set it to 20, just to test the program. If you can also explain my errors and explain how to make different patterns like a full pyramid or an inverted pyramid, that would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int sum, i, j, number=20;

    for (i=1;i<=20;++i)
    {
        sum = number-1 ;
        for (j=1;j<=i;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",sum);
            --number;
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: why do you do sum = number-1  and not number-i and forget about --number?

Answer (score 1):

This is for the half pyramid as given in your example

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int sum = 20;
    for(int i = 1; sum != -1;i++) {
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            std::cout << sum-- <<' ';
            if (sum == -1)  break;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int sum, i, j, number=20;

    for (i=1;i<=20;++i)
    {
       **sum = number** ;

    for (j=1;j<=i;j++)
    {
        printf("%d ",sum);
        --number;
    }

    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
```

}